# Replace emoji with other text

Tags: python, replace, emoji

I need to replace all emojis from text with the form `["emoji here"](emoji/1234567890)`. I wrote this code:

```
entities = [. . .] # ids for my emojies

emoji_pattern = re.compile(r"[\U0001F300-\U0001F64F\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF\u2702-\u27B0\u27BF-\u27FF\u2930-\u293F\u2980-\u29FF]")
emojis = [match.group() for match in re.finditer(emoji_pattern, text)]
emoji_dict = {emoji: [] for emoji in set(emojis)}
for i, emoji in enumerate(emojis):
    emoji_dict[emoji].append(i)
new_text = replace_emoji(emoji_dict, entities, text)


def replace_emoji(emoji_dict, entities, text):
    for emoji, indices in emoji_dict.items():
        for index in indices:
            text = re.sub(fr"{emoji}", f"[{emoji}](emoji/{entities[index]})", text)
    return text
```

`emoji_dict` looks something like this: `{'': [0], '': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}` where the numbers are the index of the value from the `entities` list

If an emoji occurs in the text only once (as in the case of ), then everything is displayed correctly: `[](emoji/1234567890)`, but if an emoji occurs several times (as in the case of ), then this is displayed like this: `[[](emoji/5235873473821159415)](emoji/5235851187235861094)[[](emoji/5235873473821159415)](emoji/5235851187235861094)`

**Tell me how can I fix this error?**

Example:

[example text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmc9Q.jpg)

```
text = '''Hello, #️⃣ user #️⃣ How's your day going?  I hope everything is going great for you!  If you have any questions, feel free to ask. I'm here to help! '''

. . .

new_text = '''Hello, [#️⃣](emoji/12352352340) user [#️⃣](emoji/12352352340) How's your day going? [](emoji/1245531421) I hope everything is going great for you! [](emoji/523424120) If you have any questions, feel free to ask. I'm here to help! [](emoji/90752893562)'''
```

Comment: `[match.group() for match in re.finditer(emoji_pattern, text)]` isn't that a long-winded way to write `re.findall(emoji_pattern, text)`?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample text and an actual value of `entities`.

Comment: now use `emojies = emoji_pattern.findall(text)`, but this does not play a strong role

Comment: When you do `for index in indices:` you do multiple replacements for those emojis. And since you include the emoji in the replacement, you get nested replacements.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `indices` list, why do you loop over it?

Comment: `indices` is a list of digits, which in turn are the desired index of the value from `entities`. `entities` this is just the id emoji from the telegram api, so it will change depending on the text

Comment: Please post sample input and the expected output.

Comment: I have edited my post by adding example text and output

Comment: I still don't see how `indices` fits into the output. You're generating the same entity for all repetitions of an emoji.

Comment: Aside: `defaultdict(list)` or `dict.setdefault()` are pythonic ways to create `emoji_dict`.

Comment: This is a list of numbers that are used as an index of entities

Comment: But doesn't that mean there should be different replacements for the same emoji?

Comment: I will ask again: Please post a [mre]. Replace `entities = [...]` with actual values. I don't see where the numbers like `12352352340` come from.

Comment: entities = ['5235851187235861094', '5235851187235861094', '5235851187235861854', 5235851187235862387, '5235851187235869854']

Comment: I get the numbers from the Message object of the telethon module

Comment: When I try your code, I don't get `#️⃣ ` in `emojis`

Comment: these numbers are the telethon premium emoji identifier

Comment: these numbers are not something important, I just need to replace them with the format [{emoji}](emoji/{emoji_id}), the code works correctly with a single emoji, but there is a problem if the same emoji occurs several times

Comment: I' just having trouble using your input. That's not an emoji, it's an ASCII `#` character followed by Unicode 0xfe0f and 0x20e3.

Comment: If an emoji appears twice, `emoji_dict` looks like `{'': [0, 1], '': [2]}`. Does that mean that the first occurrence of  should be replaced with `entities[0]` and the second should be `entities[1]`?

Comment: Yes, your right. {'': [0, 1] its entities[0] and entities[1]

Comment: If that's really what you want, why does your desired output have the same `emoji/12352352340` for both hashtag emojis?

Comment: I probably expressed it incorrectly, but the code is the same, since these are identical emoticons. You provided a really working way to solve my problem, for which I am very grateful to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
for index in indices:
    text = re.sub(..., text)
```

The first iteration replaces the emoji with `f'[{emoji}](emoji/{indices[0]})'`. Then the second iteration replaces the emoji inside the `[]` with `f'[{emoji}](emoji/{indices[1]})'`, and so on, so you get a series of nested replacements. You don't want to replace inside a previous replacement.

In your desired output, you use the same entity for all the repetitions of an emoji. So there's no need to make a list of indices for each emoji, or loop over them when making the replacements. `emoji_dict` should just have one index for each emoji, and you can replace all of them with the corresponding entity.

```
import re

text = "He llo, #️⃣ user #️⃣ How's your day going?  I hope everything is going great for you!  If you have any questions, feel free to ask. I'm here to help! "
entities = [12345, 67890, 23456, 78901] # ids for my emojies

def replace_emoji(emoji_dict, entities, text):
    for emoji, index in emoji_dict.items():
        text = re.sub(fr"{emoji}", f"[{emoji}](emoji/{entities[index]})", text)
    return text

emoji_pattern = re.compile(r"[\U0001F300-\U0001F64F\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF\u2702-\u27B0\u27BF-\u27FF\u2930-\u293F\u2980-\u29FF]")
emojis = re.findall(emoji_pattern, text)
emoji_dict = {}
for i, emoji in enumerate(set(emojis)):
    emoji_dict[emoji] = i
new_text = replace_emoji(emoji_dict, entities, text)

print(new_text)
```

output:

```
He[](emoji/67890) llo, #️⃣ user #️⃣ How's your day going? [](emoji/67890) I hope everything is going great for you! [](emoji/12345) If you have any questions, feel free to ask. I'm here to help!
```

#️⃣ and  are not replaced because they aren't matched by the regexp.